# An alternative to using this recursive function

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a function which allows me to slice an image with canvas, my loops update the x and y coordinates for my slices.

In my first version I used the following:

```
for(var x = 0; x < checkImageW; ++x) {
   for(var y = 0; y < checkImageH; ++y) {
```

Although I want the slices to be taken in rows like

```
1st Row: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2nd Row: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

So i've implemented the following recursive function (just a quick example) which increases `y` only after it has taken slices of `x[0]` to `x[WIDTH]` etc.

```
var WIDTH = 19;
var HEIGHT = 19;
var y = 0;


function slice(y) {
    for (x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++) {
        if (x === WIDTH - 1 && y < HEIGHT) {
          console.log(y);
          y++;
          slice(y);
       }
    }
}

slice(y);
```

My worry is there might be a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: You need to write `for (y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {x++}` in for statement.

Comment: The first and second solutions you tried are perfectly valid.  That said, I personally try to stay away from recursion unless I know it works well for the problem at hand and I can cover it with a lot of unit tests.  Recursion can cause memory issues for large data sets.  Also, I tend to iterate pixels sequentially and compute the x and y coordinates from the index, but again that's my preference.